# why is abandonAudioFocus not working in Android Music app

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Im using this code to get AudioFocus and it works ok with
Android  Music app ( the one preinstalled )

```
int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(meService, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
```

However when i release it with this code

```
audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(meService);
```

The Android Music app ( the one preinstalled ) does not continue playing.

if i use the `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK` it works
but Android Music app is not lowering the volume enough.

Any ides why Android Music app is not resuming playback?

im using api8 and using the `onAudioFocusChange`

Comment: after trying 4 players non of them are DUCKing. This is bad behavior from there part. Guess we have to live with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying 4 players non of them are ducking. I might be doing something wrong and would like to see that. I answer my own question that we have to live with this.

Comment: Hi Erik, Have you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should release it in `MediaPlay.onCompleteListener(){}`

Comment: This should be a comment to the OP question as it does not atempt to answer it

Answer (score 0):

This way works fine for me.

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {


 // Other stuff

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("HomeActivity", "Audio focus granted.");
        }else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED) {
            Log.i("HomeActivity", "Audio focus failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Request AudioFocus**:

```
private void requestAudioFocus(){
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        // Request audio focus for playback
        am.requestAudioFocus(this,
                // Use the music stream.
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                // Request permanent focus.
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
}
```

**Abandon AudioFocus**:

```
private void abandonAudioFocus(){
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.abandonAudioFocus(this);
}
```

Hope this would help you.